# How can I allow Duplicate Records in a Doctrine Collection

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I'm hoping there are some fellow doctrine users out there.
Here is a simplified YAML of my relationships:

```
Collection:
  columns:
    id:           { type: integer(4), notnull: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    name:         { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
  relations:
    Items:
      class: Item
      refClass: CollectionItem
      foreignAlias: Collections
      type: many
      foreignType: many

Item:
  columns:
    id:   { type: integer(4), notnull: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true }

CollectionItem:
  columns:
    id:       { type: integer(4), notnull: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    collection_id:  { type: integer(4) }
    item_id:  { type: integer(4) }
  relations:
    Collection:
      foreignAlias: CollectionItem
      foreignType: one
    Item:
      foreignAlias: CollectionItem
      foreignType: one
```

I want a collection to be able to hold many copies of the same item, but when I use the generated classes to load items like so:

```
$collection = Doctrine::getTable('Collection')->find(1);
$items = $collection->Items;
```

$items doesn't contain my duplicates.  The generated sql seems to correctly return duplicate rows:

```
SELECT  i.id AS  i__id, i.name AS  i__name, c.id AS  c__id, c.collection_id AS  c__collection_id, c.item_id AS  c__item_id, FROM item i LEFT JOIN collection_item c ON i.id = c.item_id WHERE c.collection_id IN (?) - (1)
```

I know I can get around this my making specific dql queries instead but does anyone know if there is simple setting somewhere to allow the Items collection to have duplicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to change the hydration mode to HYDRATE_SCALAR:

> This hydration mode creates a
>   flat/rectangular result set that can
>   contain duplicate data.

```
$res = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_SCALAR);
```

(or to HYDRATE_NONE)

as stated in http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/working-with-models#fetching-data

Answer (score 1):

In Doctrine you can't have duplicate objects. Each object retrieved from the database is stored only once in Doctrine. If you query for the same object twice you'll get a pointer the the same object you had already retrieved.

You can clone the object and store it in your `Doctrine_Collection`, but that will actually create another row in the database when you save the collection.

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
foreach($collection->Items as $item)
{
    // do something with $item
}
```

if i recall correctly $collection->Items isn't a real array it's a object implementing ArrayAccess / ArrayIterator